# I am trying to make a javascript function that uses the values inputed through HTML and returns a function

Tags: javascript, html

I've written the HTML and the function, but I can't figure out what to do next. Every time I input the numbers the button does not do anything when I click on it. Each input should take a number greater than or equal to zero which is the number of products. The script is supposed to take the number of products and multiply them by their varying prices and spit out a sentence at the end that includes all the different variables.

```
        <body>
    <div class = "product-page">
        <div class = "form">
                <label>Product 1
                    <input name = "product 1" type = "number" size = "25" min = "0" required>
                </label>
                <label>Product 2
                    <input name = "product 2" type = "number" size = "25" min = "0" required>
                </label>
                <label>Product 3
                    <input name = "product 3" type = "number" size = "25" min = "0" required>
                </label>
                <label>Product 4
                    <input name = "product 4" type = "number" size = "25" min = "0" required>
                </label>
                <button onclick = "earnings()">Salesperson's Earnings</button>
                <p id="click_here"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function earnings(){
            var product1 = document.getElementById("product 1").value;
            var product2 = document.getElementById("product 2").value;
            var product3 = document.getElementById("product 3").value;
            var product4 = document.getElementById("product 4").value;
            if (product1 < 0, product2 < 0, product3 < 0, product4 < 0){
                alert("Must be greater than or equal to zero");
                return;
            }
            var sales = (product1 * 75) + (product2 * 100) + (product3 * 125) + (product4 * 200);
            var comission = (sales * 0.0875);
            var total = 900 + comission;
            var text = "Salesperson's total earnings is $" + total + "that includes $900 per week plus a comission of $" + comission + "(8.75% of total sale of $"+ sales +")";
            document.getElementById("click_here").innerHTML = text;
        
        }
        

        
    </script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("yourID").value;` returns a string; you have to convert it into a number if you want to multiply it by another value. Furthermore `if (product1 < 0, product2 < 0, product3 < 0, product4 < 0)` is not valid JavaScript; I think you meant `if (product1 < 0 || product2 < 0 || product3 < 0 || product4 < 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refactor following things to work as intended:

- There is no `id` on `input`.
- `id` doesnot contain space so it would be better to add `_`.
- no need to add the `if` condition to check `product is less than 0`, You are already setting `min="0"`.But if you still checking then use `parseInt` to convert into `number`.
- I've added the default value as `value="0"`, so that we don't need to check for an empty string.

```js
function earnings() {
    var product1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("product_1").value);
    var product2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("product_2").value);
    var product3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("product_3").value);
    var product4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("product_4").value);

    var sales = product1 * 75 + product2 * 100 + product3 * 125 + product4 * 200;
    var comission = sales * 0.0875;
    var total = 900 + comission;
    var text =
        "Salesperson's total earnings is $" +
        total +
        " that includes $900 per week plus a comission of $" +
        comission +
        " (8.75% of total sale of $" +
        sales +
        ")";
    document.getElementById("click_here").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-page">
  <div class="form">
    <label>Product 1
                <input name="product 1" value="0" id="product_1" type="number" size="25" min="0" required>
            </label>
    <label>Product 2
                <input name="product 2" value="0" id="product_2" type="number" size="25" min="0" required>
            </label>
    <label>Product 3
                <input name="product 3" value="0" id="product_3" type="number" size="25" min="0" required>
            </label>
    <label>Product 4
                <input name="product 4" value="0" id="product_4" type="number" size="25" min="0" required>
            </label>
    <button onclick="earnings()">Salesperson's Earnings</button>
    <p id="click_here"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it is working now, but I am trying to figure out how to make it so the user can only input integers. As of right now, I am able to input decimals into each box any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use comma in if statement, you must use && (and) or  || (or) operator
ex:

```
 if (product1 < 0 || product2 < 0 || product3 < 0 || product4 < 0){
                    alert("Must be greater than or equal to zero");
                    return;
                }
```

and you use getElementbyID so you must prove id to inputs like this:

```
<input id="product_1" name = "product 1" type = "number" size = "25" min = "0" required>
```